# How to pass the correct parameters to this method, .net EF4, table names, where clauses

Tags: .net, entity-framework, methods

I have a few lines of code that in a loop that i'd like to refactor as a method. One of the lines is the following

```
var foo = db.tblA.Where(r => r.bar == old.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

However, when I call this method, I need to pass in different tables (tblA, tblB, tblC...) and the WHERE clause will have a different field to compare (r.Name, r.Address, r.Author...)

What would the method's signature look like to pass in those two pieces of information?

Comment: What type(s) are the properties?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
TRow MyMethod<TRow>(IQueryable<TRow> table, Expression<Func<TRow, object>> column)
```

Depending on your situation, you might want to replace `object` with `string` or with a second generic parameter.

Comment: I hate to seem like a novice, but can you show me how you'd call MyMethod given that I want to use tblA and the where clause: r.bar == old.Value ?

Comment: @Wavel: `MyMethod(tblA, r => r.bar)`.  Since `tblA` implements `IQueryable<Something>`, the generic parameter type is inferred.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm close but not close enough to make it work :( Still a lot of little issues with trying to make a generic method for my few lines of code.